# RedHat Satellite Server replica on another network

Tags: rhel, redhat-satellite, satellite

Currently I have a RedHat Satellite Server stood up on one network.  I have another network that will require a satellite server.

I'm wondering, is there a way to stand up a satellite server on the other network, where I can pull all the packages from my original satellite server, tar up all the data, then import it into the other server on the other network?

The other network is cut off from my current satellite server, so I'm trying to find a way to replicate it on another network.  I don't know much about the Satellite server setup and was wondering if such a thing is available, kind of like how IPA can create a replica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs indicate that this is possible, and refer to it as [Inter-Satellite Synchronization (ISS)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_satellite/6.13/html-single/installing_satellite_server_in_a_disconnected_network_environment/index#how-to-configure-inter-server-sync_satellite)

There are two scenarios described. The first one is a connected sync between downstream Satellite servers and one upstream Satellite server. The second one is an offline process, suitable for air-gapped networks. Your description matches the second scenario.

In the air-gapped scenario, you'd set up the upstream server to download all content. Then you would use the `hammer content-export complete` command to generate a full export. The export includes a compressed tarball of all content, plus a JSON metadata file. You would then transfer these files over to the air-gapped network, and then run a `hammer content-import` to import the data.

Future updates can be done incrementally using the `hammer content-export incremental` variant of the command.